# Start count when page is in Y position

Tags: javascript, position, counter

I have a problem with counter. 
I want something like this page: 
https://www.phishlabs.com/

I have my function:

```
function count(id, start, end, duration) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    var range = end - start;
    var minTimer = 50;
    var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));
    stepTime = Math.max(stepTime, minTimer);
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    var endTime = startTime + duration;
    var timer;
    function run() {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var remaining = Math.max((endTime - now) / duration, 0);
        var spanclass = Math.round(end - (remaining * range));
        obj.innerHTML = spanclass;
        if (spanclass == end) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }

    timer = setInterval(run, stepTime);
    run();
}
count("spanclass", 1, 648, 2000);
```

This script start count when page was loaded I need to start this function when page was on `"y"` position or on `"bottom"` position for example.

Comment: You probably want to be listening to the [`scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) event.

Answer (score 1):

> i need to start this function when page was on "y" position

then you need to call a function handler on `scroll` event,

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
  // inside this handler check if it reached y and eventually call your function
   if (window.scrollY > 444)
     yourFunction()
})
```

---

here's an example:

```js
function count(id, start, end, duration) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    var range = end - start;
    var minTimer = 50;
    var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));
    stepTime = Math.max(stepTime, minTimer);
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    var endTime = startTime + duration;
    var timer;
    function run() {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var remaining = Math.max((endTime - now) / duration, 0);
        var spanclass = Math.round(end - (remaining * range));
        obj.innerHTML = spanclass;
        if (spanclass == end) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }

    timer = setInterval(run, stepTime);
    run();
}

document.addEventListener('scroll', handler)

function handler(){
  if(window.scrollY < 900)
 return
  count("spanclass", 1, 648, 2000)
  document.removeEventListener('scroll', handler)
}
```

```css
body{
  height:2000px
}
span{
  display:block;
  margin-top:1000px
}
```

```html
<span id='spanclass'>hei</span>
```

I created a named handler so to be able to remove it once fired (you only want it once), inside `handler` you'll see a call to [`removeEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener), hope this helps...

Comment: Still don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute you function when the page is at Y position, you may try to execute the function when the page is on Y location like this:

```
function count(id, start, end, duration) {
var obj = document.getElementById(id);
var range = end - start;
var minTimer = 50;
var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));
stepTime = Math.max(stepTime, minTimer);
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var endTime = startTime + duration;
var timer;
function run() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var remaining = Math.max((endTime - now) / duration, 0);
    var spanclass = Math.round(end - (remaining * range));
    obj.innerHTML = spanclass;
    if (spanclass == end) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}

timer = setInterval(run, stepTime);
if (scrollY >= 500){
      run();
  }
}
count("spanclass", 1, 648, 2000);
```

Comment: It needs editing, meanwhile answer 1 was posted, that was correct so I did not bother editing my answer :) . I upvoted answer1 , if answer 1 solved your question, you should choose that as solution.